# Missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

Don't know what the error is but getting this error. 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_APP_INFO   
(
    TECHNOLOGY, SERVICE_DOMAIN, SYSTEM, BUSINESS_PROCESS_SEQUENCE
    , APPLICATION, BUSINESS_VALUE, INTERFACE_BATCH_JOB_SCRIPT
    , TECHNOLOGY_OWNER, TECHNOLOGY_MANAGER, TECHNOLOGY_SME
    , BUSINESS_OWNER, OWNER_NAME, PLATFORM, PREFIX
) 
VALUES 
    .NET/C++, x Recognition, Metadata & Reporting System, 
    , Aardvark, User interface to listen to TV station audio recorded by Monitoring System, Interface
    ,Graves, Graves, K.Ray, T.Nuccio
    , LANDMARK, ORACLE RAC, LDSMETA
```

Comment: use quotes for strings

Comment: ... and parentheses around the `VALUES` set, ie `VALUES ('.NET/C++', 'x Recognition', ...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add brackets and quotes:

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_APP_INFO   
(
    TECHNOLOGY, SERVICE_DOMAIN, SYSTEM, BUSINESS_PROCESS_SEQUENCE
    , APPLICATION, BUSINESS_VALUE, INTERFACE_BATCH_JOB_SCRIPT
    , TECHNOLOGY_OWNER, TECHNOLOGY_MANAGER, TECHNOLOGY_SME
    , BUSINESS_OWNER, OWNER_NAME, PLATFORM, PREFIX
) 
VALUES
( 
    '.NET/C++', 'x Recognition', 'Metadata & Reporting System', ''
    , 'Aardvark', 'User interface to listen to TV station audio recorded by Monitoring System', 'Interface'
    , 'Graves', 'Graves', 'K.Ray'
    , 'T.Nuccio', 'LANDMARK', 'ORACLE RAC', 'LDSMETA'
)
```

Quotes around values are used to group the characters between the quotes into strings; so it's clear what characters belong to each field.

Brackets after VALUES are required to show the start and the end of the current row.